# perl printf: float +1.2 should print as +001.200000

Tags: perl, formatting, floating-point, printf

I have tried this:

```
printf("%+03.6f",+1.2);
```

but it gives me

```
+1.200000
```

what I need is

```
+001.200000
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first number is the *total* number of characters, so you're asking it to provide minimum 6 digits of precision in a field of size 3 and it expands the width as needed to fit.  Try 11 instead (width of your example output).